# Using ARM to print numbers in a loop

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm a beginner ARM programmer and was wondering how to print out numbers in a loop. This is my code so far,

```
    mov r3, #0

loop: 
    add  r6, r6, #1
    push {ip, lr}
    ldr  r0, =string
    mov  r1, r6
    bl   printf    ; how do i get back to the rest of the loop after calling this?
    pop  {ip, pc}
    cmp  r6, #10
    ble  loop

    .data

    string: .asciz "number: %d\n"
```

Comment: Why are you popping `pc` inside your loop?

Answer (score 0):

> bl printf    ; how do i get back to the rest of the loop after calling
>   this?

Assuming this is the question, you return back to instruction after `bl printf` 
from inside `printf`. This is generally done via `bx lr`. Important detail is when you execute `bl`, `branch with link` instruction cpu saves the address of next instruction at `lr` (`r14`) register. This allows you to return to your previous next instruction easily by moving link register to program counter.